# Как отбирать новые задачи при множестве «рабочих»?

Tags: mysql, алгоритм, redis

Один сервер с данными, к которому подключаются несколько серверов с «рабочими» процессами.

На главном в БД хранятся некие *id* и *дата_последнего_обновления*. В Redis помечаются *id*, которые именно сейчас трогать нельзя – заняты другими «рабочими».

В работу берутся пачки по несколько сот *id*. Берутся самые давно не обновлённые, по полю *д_п_о*. Отбрасываются те, что уже «заняты» в Redis, помечаются как «в работе», обрабатываются какое-то время, обновляют *д_п_о* в БД и удаляются из Redis.

Оптимально набирать пачку ровно в L *id*. Поэтому из БД отбираю с запасом, в процессе перебора откладываю только те, что не заняты через Redis, и останавливаюсь, набрав L.

Устройство наверняка не оптимальное, но так сложилось и пока не вижу, как его разом поменять на «замечательное». Не хочется держать в БД статус занятости: работа идёт постоянно, в цикле, сервер на SSD, впустую перезаписывать такой временной инфой диск, уменьшая его ресурс, кажется неправильным.

Как поступать по мере изменения числа подключённых «рабочих» – увеличивать этот запас при выборке из БД или есть более разумное решение?